# Cross Domain RSS (XML) Client Side Only Solution?

Tags: javascript, xml, rss, cross-domain

Assuming my conditions for building a RSS feed reader were I had to provide only a Javascript snippet. The RSS is cross domain and is only XML. What are my options and how can I implement them? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cross-domain XHR with appropriate [HTTP access control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) use.

Comment: thanks eli - i'm going to research this but do you know off-hand if it works in IE6+, FF, Safari, and Chrome? thnx

Comment: IE8+ (with it's own proprietary `XDomainRequest` constructor), Firefox 3+, no idea for Safari, and Chrome 4+. Also, mind accepting my answer?

Comment: @bresson: You said "client side only" so this will depend on whether you control all the RSS feeds you are interested in, or whether they already implement HTTP access control.